# How can we highlight the link when that particular link is clicked and making other links normal?

Tags: java, html, css

Suppose I have a 3 links. If I click one among them, that particular link must be highlighted and displayed in a bold or any other way. When we click another link again, the remaining must come to normal.

Is it possible to do for the links? Can any one give any solution please?

I have written this code but it is not staying as highlighted in the other page, this is my code

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
 $(function() {
        $('#menu span').click(function(e) {
            $('div').find('span').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
        });
    });
 </script>
<title>Header</title>
<style>
 #menu span a {
    display:inline-block;
    color:blue;
    cursor:pointer;
    padding:10px;
        text-decoration:none;
}
.active { 
    font-weight: bold;
    border:1px solid;

}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h2 style="color:blue">Employee Details</h2>
<div id="menu">
    <span> <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/bulkImport">Menu 1</a></span>
    <span ><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/fileUploadForm">Menu 2</a></span>
    <span ><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/deleteMultiple">Menu 3</a></span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please give me the solution. How to keep that link as highlighted even when the link is clicked and it goes to next page. Even it must be highlighted in the next page till the other link is clicked.

Comment: Have You been trying anything?

Comment: have you familiar with pseudo elements?
try using `:active`,  `:hover` and `:focus` with your links.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a onclick function to change the class of the element.

If you have jQuery in your application, it's as simple as

```
<a href="http://foo.bar" onclick="$(this).addClass('clicked')">click me</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here You have ready solution using [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) JavaScript framework:

**HTML:**

```html
<div id="menu">
    <a href="" title="">Item 1</a>
    <a href="" title="">Item 2</a>
    <a href="" title="">Item 3</a>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```css
div#menu a { padding: 10px; }
div#menu a.active { font-weight: bold; }
```

**JavaScript:**

```js
$(function() {
    $('div#menu a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var $this = $(this);

        $this.closest('div').find('a').removeClass('active');
        $this.addClass('active');
    });
});
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ps4af646/

Comment: Downvoter: Reveal yourself and put a comment with purpose of Your actions... if you dare...

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.mylist li').click(function() {

  $('.mylist li').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');

});
```

```css
.active {
  background: red;
}
li {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="mylist">
  <li class="active"><a href="#">link 1</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">link 2</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">link 3</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this link [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ps4af646/6/)

**CSS**

```
  #menu span a {
    display:inline-block;
    color:blue;
    cursor:pointer;
    padding:10px;
        text-decoration:none;
}
.active { 
    font-weight: bold;
    border:1px solid;

}
```

**HTML**

```
    <div id="menu">
    <span> <a href="#">Menu 1</a></span>
    <span ><a href="#">Menu 2</a></span>
    <span ><a href="#">Menu 3</a></span>
</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
    $(function() {
    $('#menu span').click(function(e) {
        $('div').find('span').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

Comment: OMFG. Nice answer copying.

Comment: @ Krzysztof Trzos your jquery and my jquery is different and the answer is depends on jquery.

Comment: @Empiro You're joking, right? You literally copied and slighty edited my answer and code from jsFiddle.